# Intersection of values in a common column of two dataframes- Pandas, Python3

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, intersection

I have 2 dataframes; dataframe main and dataframe mini, with exactly the same headers but with different values in them however there is some overlap. How would I get the duplicate values within a single column (e.g. Column 'Name').

Example:

dataframe main

```
Name    size    length
foo      1         2
foo2     3         4
foo3     5         6  
foo4     7         8
```

dataframe mini

```
Name     size     length
foox      60       70
foo3       3        4
fooy      50       60
foo4      7        8
```

psuedo code: `intersect(column='Name', of='dataframe mini', against='dataframe main')`

proposed out : `(foo3,foo4)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html#pandas.Series.isin) to mask the row values that are in another df:

```
In [52]:
main.loc[main['Name'].isin(mini['Name']), 'Name']

Out[52]:
2    foo3
3    foo4
Name: Name, dtype: object
```